# Change the state of the condition variable for a while loop outside the while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, global-variables, keyboard-events, python-multithreading

I am currently trying to start and stop a while loop by a pressing a key  (start) and stopping by releasing the key.

So something like this:

```
from pynput import keyboard
global condition
condition = False

def on_press(key):
    global condition
    if key == keyboard.Key.cmd_r:
        print('pressed cmd_r'.format(key))
        condition = True
    else:
        print('incorrect character {0}, press cmd_r'.format(key))


def on_release(key):
    global condition
    print('{0} released'.format(key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.cmd_r:
        condition = False
        #keyboard.Listener.stop
        #return False


with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

while condition==True:
    print "Condition true"
```

I am not sure why this is not working?.. 
It should in my head?

Comment: is it maybe that the condition is False at the beginning, so it never actually starts the while loop and the process ends?

Comment: also `condition` should be declared `global` in the callbacks

Comment: I've set the `global` at the top but should it also be done inside the callbacks?

Comment: but yes @Jean-FrançoisFabre I've tried that but it still doesn't work..

Comment: @PietroTortella Yes.. could be, but adding global doesn't seem to help either..

Comment: Pietro is right. It must be `True` at the start or it won't enter the loop. And your loop is CPU intensive. Maybe you should consider adding `time.sleep()`

Comment: But the intent is to start the while loop when the key is pressed, and stop it when it is released @Jean-FrançoisFabre ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when you call `listener.join()` your code waits at this point for the thread to complete. But it never will complete because it's always listening! Instead you want to call `listener.start()` so that the thread runs in the background and you are free to do what you want.

Sharing variables between threads is not generally accepted, so here I make a modified listener class that associates the variable `key_pressed` to itself when a key is pressed, and `None` when it is released. You can then do what you want with this variable by checking it at any time in a separate loop by calling `listener.key_pressed`

```
from pynput import keyboard
import time


class MyListener(keyboard.Listener):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyListener, self).__init__(self.on_press, self.on_release)
        self.key_pressed = None

    def on_press(self, key):
        self.key_pressed = key

    def on_release(self, key):
        self.key_pressed = None


listener = MyListener()
listener.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print listener.key_pressed
```

Note that if you don't include a delay with `time.sleep` as above, you will overload the buffer and lead to delays in the output. Just put a small delay if you want it fast, but not zero.

Comment: Also to be sure that you catch the key press event, you may want to modify the `on_release` method to to have `self.key_pressed = key` also. However this makes the listener useless after a single key press event but maybe that's what you want!

Comment: This does look like something i was looking for, and `on_release` has to stop the action, so resetting it to `None` should be correct..   Saying should as I seem to have some problems implementing the functionality..

Comment: This will sound silly, but how do check whether a key is pressed?
I can't seem to test the variable `listener.key_pressed` with any keys it prints out besides none?

Comment: Ahh.. found the solution.

Comment: Yes, you could have the `self.key_pressed = True` to begin with, then have both `on_press` and `on_release` set `self.key_pressed = False`. Then for your loop you could just have `while listener.key_pressed:` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may need something like main loop where you can include your special while loop to achieve this.

**Update 1 - How? (wrong)**

```
while True:
    # main loop
    while condition:
        # your special loop
        # do something...
    time.sleep(0.1) # sleep 0.1 seconds
```

The "main loop" is an infinite loop and executes included instructions every 0.1 second. Hence you provide the ability to keep checking the `condition`. If the `condition == True` your "special loop" is going to execute and it stops when the `condition == False`, and then  the "main loop" continues its execution.

**Update 2 - The implementation (correct)**

Ok, I've run the code and I see that the "main loop" solution isn't right here. For now, I have quick, tested solution, based on multithreading:

```
import time
import threading

from pynput import keyboard


condition = False


def my_special_task():
    global condition
    while condition:
        print("condition = %s" % condition)
        time.sleep(0.1)


def on_press(key):
    global condition
    if key == keyboard.Key.ctrl_r:
        print('Pressed ctrl_r')
        condition = True
        thread = threading.Thread(target=my_special_task)
        thread.start()
    else:
        print("Incorrect KEY: %s, press ctrl_r instead" % key)


def on_release(key):
    global condition
    print("%s released" % key)
    if key == keyboard.Key.ctrl_r:
        condition = False


with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: but how?... I seriously have no idea on how it should be?

Comment: and how/where do you read input from the keyboard, or alter the `condition` of the while loop?

Comment: I admit that the "main loop" solution is wrong one, but I found the proper solution and updated the answer. Sorry for the misleading. I think it requires some multithreading knowledge in Python to understand and solve problems like this one.

Comment: Oh yes. This seem more correct, but I somehow seem to be stuck in the loop with no way of getting out.